# adding values from a class in java

Tags: java, class, arraylist

There was a question in my book that said this (there are no answers):

> Suppose we have a class Beta declared with the header:
>
> ```
> class Beta extends Alpha
> ```
>
> so Beta is a subclass of Alpha, and in class Alpha there is a method
>   with header:
>
> ```
> public int value(Gamma gam) throws ValueException
> ```
>
> Write a static method called addValues which takes an object which
>   could be of type `ArrayList<Alpha>` or `ArrayList<Beta>`, and also an
>   object of type `Gamma`. A call to the method addValues must return the
>   sum obtained by adding the result of a call of value on each of the
>   objects in the ArrayList argument, with the Gamma argument as the
>   argument to each call of value. Any call of value which causes an
>   exception of type ValueException to be thrown should be ignored in
>   calculating the sum.

My Attempt:

```
public static int addValues(ArrayList<? extends Alpha> arr, Gamma gam) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
        try {
            sum += arr.get(i) + gam;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            i++;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Although I know for starters that the line `sum += arr.get(i) + gam` is going to give me an error, because they are not straight forward `int`s that can be added. The book provides no more information on the question so what I have written here is everything required for the question.

Comment: The question says ValueException, not Exception.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are supposed to call the `value` method in order to get the values you are supposed to be adding.

Beside that, you can use the enhanced for loop to make your code cleaner.

```
public static int addValues(ArrayList<? extends Alpha> arr, Gamma gam) 
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (Alpha alpha : arr) {
        try {
            sum += alpha.value(gam);
        } catch (ValueException e) {
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Ahhh yes, I should've understood the question better! I didn't notice this, thank you! (Will mark correct once timer has passed).

Comment: You should also only catch a ValueException, per the problem statement.  If you get an OutOfMemoryException or something, then you wouldn't want to keep summing.

Answer (score 1):

Use wild card with bounded type as Alpha as you want to access the value then use  arr.

```
public static int addValues(ArrayList<? extends Alpha> arr, Gamma gam) 
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (Alpha alpha : arr) {
        try {
            sum += alpha.value(gam);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Regarding the second question of overriding the equal function

```
public boolean equals(Gamma g) {
        if(g!= null && g instanceof Alpha && value(g) == value(this.myGam)){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```